# Docker silent Healthcheck?

Tags: docker, curl, dockerfile, containers, health-check

I want to add a `healthcheck` to my container, and it's working fine, but it's spamming my container log every time it checks, which is noisy and makes gleaning the important stuff out harder than need be:

```
today at 12:44:38 AM127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2022:00:44:37 -0500] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 427 "-" "curl/7.12.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.12.0 ipv6 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23"
```

Every 30 seconds.

I want to have it continue working normally, minus the log spam. I've tried this so far, thinking I could send the output to `> /dev/null`, but no luck; it still sends to the container log (stdout):

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl -ILfSs http://localhost:80 -A "HealthCheck" > /dev/null || exit 1
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The log message isn't from the healthcheck process. It's from your application that logs that a request came in. It's true that the request originated from your healthcheck, but your application logs all requests.

Comment: @HansKilian I'm not well versed in linux; I assumed (incorrectly, but not sure why) adding the `> /dev/null` to the curl command would send curl's output to silent bliss (while still somehow magically not breaking the actual healthcheck function)?

Comment: My point is that the output isn't from curl. It's from your application which logs that a request came in *from* curl. To remove the logging of those requests, you'd need to somehow set up a filter in your application so it doesn't log those requests.

Comment: @HansKilian hmmm, Apache is the app. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this'll help: https://serverfault.com/questions/91152/filter-entries-from-going-into-apache-logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just following up on my question, I ended up doing this in Apache's `000-default` (site config) file:

```
# + --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- +
# | Prevent access.log spam of the Docker Healthcheck                                                                           |
# | Refs:                                                                                                                       |
# | https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html                                                                     |
# | https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/need-to-exclude-certain-messages-from-apache-access_log-4175543280 |
# + --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- +
<IfModule setenvif_module>
    # If UA matches healthcheck, set 'nolog' env var, which we exclude from the log(s) in the logformat section below.
    BrowserMatchNoCase ^healthcheck nolog
</IfModule>

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined env=!nolog
```

Note that I had set the custom health check UserAgent to: `HealthCheck: Docker/1.0`:

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl -ILfSs http://localhost:80 -A "HealthCheck: Docker/1.0" || exit 1
```

Thanks Hans, for pointing me in the right direction.